# Tracking an expected set of Kafka events

Tags: apache-kafka, distributed-system

Say I have N cities and each will report their temperature for the hour (H) by producing Kafka events. I have a complex model I want to run but want to ensure it doesn't attempt to kick-off before all N are read.

Say they are being produced in batches, I understand that to ensure at-least-once consumption, if a consumer fails mid-batch then it will pick up at the front of the batch. I have built this into my model to count by unique Cities (and if a city is sent multiple times it will overwrite existing records).

My current plan is to set it up as follows:

1. An application creates an initial event which says "Expect these N cities to report for H o'clock".
2. The events are persisted (in db, Redis, etc) by another application. After writing, it produces an event which states how many unique cities have been reported in total so far for H.
3. Some process matches the initial "Expect N" events with "N Written" events. It alerts the rest of the system that the data set for H is ready for creating the model when they are equal.

**Does this problem have a name and are there common patterns or libraries available to manage it?**
Does the solution as outlined have glaring holes or overcomplicate the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're describing sounds like an [Aggregator](https://www.enterpriseintegrationpatterns.com/patterns/messaging/Aggregator.html), described by Gregor Hohpe and Bobby Woolf's "Enterprise Integration Patterns" as:

> a special Filter that receives a stream of messages and identifies messages that are correlated. Once a complete set of messages has been received [...], the Aggregator collects information from each correlated message and publishes a single, aggregated message to the output channel for further processing.

This could be done on top of Kafka Streams, using its built-in aggregation, or with a stateful service like you suggested.

One other suggestion -- designing processes like this with event-driven choreography can be tricky. I have seen strong engineering teams fail to deliver similar solutions due to diving into the deep end without first learning to swim. If your scale demands it and your organization is already primed for event-driven distributed architecture, then go for it, but if not, consider an orchestration-based alternative (for example, AWS Step Functions, Airflow, or another workflow orchestration tool). These are much easier to reason about and debug.

Comment: This aligns well with the described problem. We have the architecture but never hurts to evaluate other alternatives so we will look into orchestration-based as well.